# Xamarin iOS transitioning between interfaces

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile-development

I've recently completed an Android app in Xamarin and am now working through creating an iOS application. I'm not sure if I've missed something extremely basic here, but I'm having trouble understanding how you transition from one screen to another.

In the MultiScreen demo app, this is achieved with a navigation controller and segue. I also saw the code sample which shows you to do this manually, calling the:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController(YourView, true);
```

And this works fine assuming you want to be able to navigate between the two.

The first thing my users see is a login screen. If the user successfully logs in, I want to send them to a home screen. As you can imagine, it makes no sense that you would 'go back' to the login page. I've seen it is possible to hide the navigation bar, but I just wanted to check first... Is there an alternative way to transition to the home page without using a NavigationController ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide and show the navigation "Back" button

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, true);  //Hide
    //this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (false, true);//Show
}
```

if you dont want to use a UINavigationController then you can use `PresentViewController()` and `DismissViewController()` to navigate

```
nextViewController nextVC = new nextViewController();
PresentViewController(nextVC, true, null);
```

There is also an [example here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile/blob/master/MonoTouch/Samples/MediaPickerSample/AppDelegate.cs) that demonstrates how to use those 2 methods

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did see that it was possible to hide it. But can you just clarify - is a NavigationController required in order to move to to the next screen, regardless of whether you need to be able to link back to it? This wasn't clear in the documentation on the Xamarin website, hence my confusion :S

Comment: No a UiNavigationController isnt necessary to navigate , but it simplify things alot , especially for someone who is not very familiar with iOS.

Comment: If thw answer helped you please accept it. Thank you

Comment: Happy to credit you for the answer. Are you able to point me in the direction of some Xamarin documentation which shows how to do it without a Navigation Controller?